# slow transition between images on JavaScript slideshow? (especially using chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image-scaling

I've developed a website, 'www.malenemicha.com'. It seems like the JavaScripts are running very slow, when I scroll through the images and when I try to access the subpage 'www.malenemicha.com/portfolio'.

Google Chrome is much slower than the other browsers. Could this be a JavaScript issue?

I've used profiling tools on the website, and it seems like the code is fine.

I've also used validator, and every html code seems to be valid.

Please, can anybody help regarding this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps its your huge image files.

http://www.imageoptimizer.net/

With all these profiling tools, analyzers, and all your bedazzled tests, I think you overloooked the fact that the site loads like 20MB of data, quite the payload.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But I've seen lots of websites with much more images running much faster. Mostly this is flash based websites. Do you think that JQuery is unable to run this amount of images?

Comment: And why is Chrome much slower than the rest of the browsers?